# Mandated vectorization for gfortran compiler

Tags: fortran, vectorization, gfortran, simd

I want to execute a Fortran loop in a vectorial way with a vector processor (Intel Xeon). I recently got the way doing this with the Intel compiler ifort that we can add `!DIR$ SIMD` before the loop.

But when I work with gfortran compiler, I find that all the vectorization operations are automatic. For example,

```
      PROGRAM MAIN1
      IMPLICIT NONE

      DOUBLE PRECISION :: X(100)
      INTEGER          :: NELEM = 100, NELMAX = 100, LV = 4
      INTEGER          :: IKLE(100), I, IB, IELEM
      DOUBLE PRECISION :: W(100)
      DOUBLE PRECISION :: MASKEL(100)
      LOGICAL          :: MSK = .FALSE.

      DO I = 1, 100
        X(I) = I
        IKLE(I) = I
        W(I) = 0
      END DO

      DO IB = 1,(NELEM+LV-1)/LV
  !------------loop to vectorize------------------
      DO IELEM = 1+(IB-1)*LV , MIN(NELEM,IB*LV)
        X(IKLE(IELEM)) = X(IKLE(IELEM)) + W(IELEM)
      ENDDO ! IELEM 
  !-----------------------------------------------
      ENDDO ! IB

      PRINT *, X
      END PROGRAM
```

Part of the output of `gfortran main1.f -O3 -fopt-info-optimized` is printed below

```
main1.f:18:0: note: not vectorized: not suitable for gather load _33 = x[_32];
main1.f:18:0: note: bad data references.
main1.f:18:0: note: not vectorized: not enough data-refs in basic block.
main1.f:18:0: note: not vectorized: not enough data-refs in basic block.
```

Since the program output X is right when the loop is compiled by ifort in a mandated vectorization mode, I wonder if there's also a similar way for gfortran.

Comment: Can you get rid of the IKLE(IELEM)? There is no such gfortran directive I am aware of. You may want the SIMD directive from OpenMP 4.0. I wouldn't normally refer to Intel processors as "vectorial".

Comment: Yeah I also did that and found it works. But unfortunately I can't get rid of it, it's part of the calculation.

Comment: Are you sure you got any speedup with ifort? If you mandate it it will vectorize even loops which are not profitable to be vectorized.

Comment: Maybe not in this demo. But it is likely to be useful in another one which is much larger

Comment: It is not clear that vectorization will accelerate this loop : the arithmetic intensity of the code is low so it seems to be memory bound. Also, it may be profitable to make a random read on W instead of doing a random write on X if you can.

Comment: I would be cautious even there, make some tests you gain any speedup, only after that you can say gfortran is wrong in not vectorizing it.

Comment: @VladimirF But you have the point, I'll check it. Maybe the mandated vectorization is not a good idea

Comment: Also read https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/509157 for some interesting points about vectorization in recent versions of compilers on the Intel architecture.

Comment: To check if your loop is vectorized you can compile the code with the ``-g`` option and check the assembly : ``objdump -d -S a.out`` will give you the assembly. Then you can search (or grep) for vector instructions (addps or vaddps here). Also, if you don't give an option to gfortran such as -mavx for instance, i think that gfortran will produce SSE2 code by default which will not be able to vectorize complicated loops.

Answer (score 0):

In this case with scatter stores, forcing vectorization by directive could change the results when there are repeated entries in the index array IKLE(:), as it doesn't preserve the sequence of memory access.  As far as I know, the only directive of this nature available in gfortran is !$omp simd, which gfortran is free to ignore. omp simd directives are active only when corresponding compile options are set.
ifort offers (-opt-report4 in recent versions) an assessment of peak speedup possible by vectorization.  I don't know whether that assessment is based on the declared array sizes.  If there is a speedup, it would be achieved more by changing the operation sequence than by actual SIMD parallelism.

Comment: Instruction sequences generated by ifort and gfortran do preserve the order of stores, in case of repeats.  In avx512 there are conflict resolution instructions for use in case they may be needed.